# Laravel 5.2 add Auth::id() to Posted data

Tags: php, laravel-5

I started to learn working with Laravel 5.2 framework about 3 hours ago ^^

I did add task form and it works but i made `task_starter_id` column in database

and data that posted by form is only task title and content from input values

And finally my question is i want to add starter id with `Auth::id();` i can't do it

I know the old way to post data in laravel 4

```
$task = new App\Tasks();
 // inputs
$task->save();
```

But i want to do this with laravel 5 way if it's possible

Here's route.php

```
Route::post('tasks', function(Request $req) {

    $data = $req::all();
    $data['task_starter_id'] = Auth::id();

    $task = App\Tasks::create($data);

    return redirect('tasks');

});
```

Blade template :

```
            <div class="panel-body">
                    {!! Form::open() !!}
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('task_title', 'Task Title :') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('task_title', null, 
                                    array(
                                        'class' => 'form-control', 
                                        'id' => 'task_title', 
                                        'placeholder' => 'Task Title'
                                        )) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('task_content', 'Task Content :') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('task_content', null, 
                                    array(
                                        'class' => 'form-control', 
                                        'id' => 'task_content', 
                                        'placeholder' => 'Task Content'
                                        )) !!}
                </div>
                {!! Form::submit('Add Task', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm']) !!}
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
```

Model

```
class Tasks extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'tasks';

    protected $fillable = ['task_title','task_content','task_starter_id'];

}
```

**I hope that i explained perfectly what i want, Thanks all.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I insert into table form data with user id in laravel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697382/how-do-i-insert-into-table-form-data-with-user-id-in-laravel)